# Sort two files according first column with special conditions

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, compare

I found similar topics to comparing and sorting files, but no one match my needs. Try to explain on example:

```
cat file1

D value1 value2 value[n]
Z value1 value2 value[n]
H value1 value2 value[n]
A value1 value2 value[n]
C value1 value2 value[n]

cat file2

C value11 value22 value[n]
D value11 value22 value[n]
A value11 value22 value[n]
```

Desire output:

cat output

```
D value11 value22 value[n]
Z ------- ------- -------[n]
H ------- ------- -------[n]
A value11 value22 value[n]
C value11 value22 value[n]
```

So compare according first column file2 with file1 - if match print whole line file2, but keep sorting according file1. If no match print just first column following dots (-------). Number of column both files is different.

Any idea or help would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If no match print just first column following dots (-------).

Therefore I think the `[n]` should be replaced by `-`s as well.

then this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}!a[$1]{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)gsub(/./,"-",$i)}7' f2 f1
```

gives:

```
D value1 value2 value[n]
Z ------ ------ --------
H ------ ------ --------
A value1 value2 value[n]
C value1 value2 value[n]
```

#### Edit

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if(a[$1])$0=a[$1];else for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)gsub(/./,"-",$i)}7' f2 f1
```

gives:

```
D value11 value22 value[n]
Z ------ ------ --------
H ------ ------ --------
A value11 value22 value[n]
C value11 value22 value[n]
```

Comment: Hello Kent, thank you for reply. Nice solution, but I have on output good sorting but values are from file2 not from file1.

Comment: @Paul oh, I didn't notice it, but it is easy to change. check the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} 
{
  if (a[$1])
     $0=a[$1]
  else {
     s=$1
     gsub(/[^[:blank:]]/, "-")
     $1=s
     $NF=$NF "[n]"
} 1' file2 file1

D value11 value22 value[n]
Z ------ ------ --------[n]
H ------ ------ --------[n]
A value11 value22 value[n]
C value11 value22 value[n]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava, sorting according first column of file1 works great, but it gaves mi values from file1 - I need sort according file1 if match, get values from file2. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Isn't this answer already doing that? It goes through all records of `file1` and prints matching lines. If not matching it prints hyphens instead.

Comment: No really, it prints just value1 form file1, I need print value11 form file2.

Comment: Thank you at first. If you look at example - value1 are values from file1 and value11 are values from file2. I need to sort file2 according to first column of file1 and print values from file2. If values do not exist in file2 I need just print tab (or -- or any other character). So easy say - from file1 keep just first column - from file2 its values (if exist). I hope it is more clear?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I've further updated my answer accordingly.